# How can I reference dynamically expandable/shrinkable excel tables in Excel 2010?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

Our system uses template spreadsheets, each template having two sheets, Data and RawData. RawData contains excel tables with data populated by an application. The users are responsible for creating the reports (on the Data sheet) they want, based on the data in the RawData sheet. Now, the data in the tables can vary, a table can have 5 rows today, next day it can have 10 rows.

If on RawData I have Table1 with column1, how would I reference the data in this column on the Data sheet in a way that would account for the growth/shrinkage of the data in Table1?

I thought I could use array formula and reference and use the array formula {=Table1[column1]} but when I define it I always have to specify a fixed number of rows. There seems to be no way to specify the number of rows/columns the array formula would expand to and derive this number from a formula, similar with the way dynamic ranges work. If I select too may rows, the array formula puts the #NA value in the cells that go beyond the available items.

Thanks

PS. Using VBA is not an option.

Comment: You definitely can use something like `=SUM(Table1[column1])` and it will always refer to the entire contents of column1.  Is that what you are asking?

Comment: What kind of functions are you using to reference the RawData sheet?

Comment: There are some great formula workaround for this situation, but they are all very case specific so it's hard to see which (if any) method would solve your issue.

Usually it's a hybrid ob `countifs`, `match`, `if`, and `offset` working together to dynamically select and manipulate a table within a given space. If you can provide lots of details of the table layout in the sheet  I'd be happy to provide an answer.

Comment: @Stepan1010: I want to simply get the column data as is. The user would apply formatting (conditional formatting as well). The idea is that I want the data to extend if the original data is grows. I am not worried about aggregate formulas. I know I can handle those even when the data shrinks or grows.

Comment: To give you a more concrete example, let's say that, in the RawData sheet, I have Table1 with Column1 that today contains the values 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. The user wants to apply a simple transformation and multiply these values with 10, so in the Data sheet, the user needs to display 10, 20, 30, 40 and 50. This can be done with an array formula, for instance. But the tricky thing is that tomorrow when the template is re-evaluated Table1 can have 10 values or 2 values. The user's data should grow or shrink as well, and this is what I am looking for.

Comment: Are there multiple tables of data on the RawData sheet? Or is it just one table?

Comment: Yes, there are multiple tables. The user can build their own reports from multiple tables and cherry pick the data they want. Again, my issue is with the pattern where you need all the data in a table column and you don't know how many rows are going to be in that table.

Comment: @costa It's definitely doable, but it's hard to see what you're trying to do without more detail. I've made a workbook with tables that pull data from a "RawData" table, including a summary table that pulls from the various tables. I used lots of array formulas. In some cases, I created an array formula which would have to be manually filled into lower cells. One monster formula is used to populate a table with unique IDs. Since it's possible for people to add new IDs, I need to manually expand this table and drag the formula down until IDs stop showing up.

Comment: Fun times! `{=IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(INDEX(LodgTbl[PC], MATCH(0, COUNTIF($A$1:A1, LodgTbl[PC]), 0)),INDEX(MealTbl[PC], MATCH(0, COUNTIF($A$1:A1, MealTbl[PC]), 0))),INDEX(TransTbl[PC], MATCH(0, COUNTIF($A$1:A1, TransTbl[PC]), 0))),INDEX(MiscTbl[PC], MATCH(0, COUNTIF($A$1:A1, MiscTbl[PC]), 0))), "")}`

Comment: And this was its friend to sum up the values in the same row as the ID ("PC"): `=IF([@PC]<>"",
SUMIF(LodgTbl[PC],[@PC],LodgTbl[Cost])+
SUMIF(MiscTbl[PC],[@PC],MiscTbl[Cost])+
SUMIF(MealTbl[PC],[@PC],MealTbl[Cost])+
SUMIF(TransTbl[PC],[@PC],TransTbl[Cost]),"")` So, array formulas work fine, but we'd have to know what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Zairja: Thanks. I think you said 'I need to manually expand this table'. I don't want to do anything manually if the data grows or shrinks. To use another paradigm, what I want to do is like a sql view. If the base table changes the view changes as well. Pivot tables in combination with dynamic ranges are actually closest to what I want because changes in the underlining data are reflected in them (when you refresh the pivot table)

Comment: Perhaps you can provide some sample data or an example of something specific you're trying to accomplish with array formulas involving table columns. Maybe using pivot tables or different formulas could solve your problem?

Comment: @Zairja: I already explained what I want to accomplish to my best of ability. I don't think providing an example would add more to what I just wrote in this thread. Pivot tables come closest. Thanks for the formulas.

Comment: @Zairja: actually, I changed my mind :-) check this spreadsheet out: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/35370420/pivot_tables.xlsx. If you add another item to the list and refresh the pivot table, the pivot table will incorporate that new line. This is what I want to do: like a table on top of a table/range or it's just a view of a table/range. Take a look at the names: Formulas->Name manager. The pivot table data is specified as that range.

Comment: yea, so pivot tables summarize data - and allow you to display data in different ways - Is that what you were trying to do? Things like that are part of the key ingredients people need to know to understand your question. So basically people need to know what you are trying to do with the data on the RawData sheet?.

Comment: @Stepan1010: Here is the workflow: .Net app injects data into an excel file in the form of excel tables on the Raw Data sheet. User takes takes excel file and writes his own report on the Data sheet based on the data in the Raw Data sheet. User saves file. App refreshes the data on the Raw Data sheet and recalculates the spreadsheet. App presents the content of the Data sheet to user. If the numbers of rows change in one of the tables the Data sheet should reflect the new content.

Comment: @Stepan1010: (continued) if the user wants to report the data from one of the tables and add his or her columns he/she has to do it in a way that accounts for the shrinkage/growth of the data. To come back to the pivot table example, if I add a new beverage and refresh the pivot table that beverage will show up automatically in the pivot table. If I were to attach an external table to the spreadsheet excel would get the data from that table. If I chose to refresh the table Excel will re-run the query and update the content.

Comment: @Stepan1010: (continued) It's the same concept but instead of an external table you'd use a dynamic range. Sorry, but I don't know how else to explain it.

Comment: @Stepan1010: one more note, in the workflow, the app runs every day and it refreshes the data. The user doesn't make any changes anymore to the Data sheet (of course unless some changes are necessary). The report has to run daily or ad-hoc for any day of the year.

Comment: I think I understand what you're going for... Short of using a Pivot Table or VBA, there's no way to make your table automatically grow or shrink. You could put in a full column of formulas and just hide the fact they don't evaluate to anything. Your question states that your array formula puts `#NA`, so perhaps you can modify those array formulas to account for empty/extra rows or catch errors. I'd still like an example of an array formula you're trying to use for a table (sample data) to see where the problem is, if it's something that we can modify or solve with a pivot table.

Comment: Most excel functions allow blanks. Take vlookup for example - you can just reference the largest possible area your data would be contained within. If you are trying to do something with reporting on specific time periods you could try out - Dynamic Named Ranges - http://www.gilliganondata.com/index.php/2010/08/17/excel-dynamic-named-ranges-never-manually-updating-your-charts-2/ - This would display the reporting period so people don't think your reporting on a period later than you are. - It's hard to help unless we know which functions users are using to reference the RawData sheet.

Comment: @Zairja: Thank you both for your input. I don't think it is possible to do what I want other than using pivot tables. Just to let you know I have a programming background, I've done a lot of sql programming and reports using different products. If you look from this angle, I am basically trying to use the concept of a sql view and I am trying to fit a simple reporting pattern in Excel - the simplest there is, I guess, select the data from a table. In all these years I don't think Excel advanced in this direction even though I think it could.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, it is not possible to do what I want, unless I resort to pivot tables or make use of some assumptions(use the knowledge that a table cannot have more than a certain known number of rows).

Comment: There is always a way to do what you want. But like Gimp said at the very beginning they are all formula specific(naturally because formulas have different ways of inputting paramaters/arguments). If you can tell us what specific functions you are using that are returning errors we could probably help more.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the OFFSET function in the NamedRange formula entry?  You can put your table in its own sheet and use this.  You just need to make sure that your Height and Width reference always has data in it*.

```
=OFFSET(Reference, Rows, Cols, Height, Width)
Reference = Start of your table
Rows = 0 - no offset
Cols = 0 - no offset
Height = COUNTA($A:$A) - counts the number of entries in column A
Width = COUNTA($6:$6) - counts the number of entries in row 6
```

If I called this named range 'testrange' then I could just go to a cell and say `=rows(testrange)` and it would return the value of the dynamic range

*You can wrap your COUNTA in MAX like so "MAX(1,COUNTA($A:$A))" to prevent reference errors when there is no data in the table